# Android Database add column

Tags: android, database, sqlite

is there any simple way how to add column or update column via SQlite in Android?

Now I am using raw SQL:

```
public void addColumn(String tableName, String ColumnName, String ColumnType, String AdditionalDetails){
    SQLiteDatabase db=dtbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+tableName+" ADD COLUMN "+ColumnName+" "+ColumnType+" "+AdditionalDetails+";");
    Log.d("TAG","FINISHED");
}
```

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks correct. In SQLite you only can ADD column and you cannot UPDATE it. Also refer to some restrictions when [adding column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Comment: In my app I ended up with renaming old table and creating the new one.  Though it's always possible to create new columns and not use old ones. 
As you can see SQLite by definition does not have options to delete or to update individual column.